# How to consume an xml web service in a metro app?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

How can i consume  consume  XML web service in Metro app?

Comment: How would you consume the service in any other application?

Comment: REST or SOAP? That will make a difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by reading up on the new [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and a Microsoft [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee) demonstrating it.

Then check out the sample Metro Flickr app as part of the [Cocoon Framework](http://cocoon.codeplex.com/) sample which connects to Flickr's Web API and displays results via XML (and illustrates fantastic data virtualization and placeholder use on large data sets within a metro app mind you).